# change string based on condition

Tags: r, string

I have a dataframe like the one below.

I want to add a character at the begining of the strings in the year variable, which would variate based on the first character.

```
year <- c("991", "990", "985", "975", "001", "003")
name <- c("John", "Anna", "Amy", "Sarah", "Bob", "John")

test <- data.frame(year, name)
```

The condition would be:

- If first letter in the string == 9, than add "1" in front of it,
- If first letter in the string == 0, than add "2" in front of it
- Else add "7"

Not sure if there is a way to combine a for loop and strsplit to solve this?

My attemnt:

```
  paste0(strsplit(test$year, '')[[1]][1], collapse = '')
```

With this I get the first character of the first row, but im not sure how to put this in a loop, and than add a conditional inside it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a nested `ifelse` statement,

```
ifelse(substring(test$year, 1, 1) == 9, paste0(1, test$year), 
       ifelse(substring(test$year, 1, 1) == 0, paste0(2, test$year), paste0(7, test$year)))
#[1] "1991" "1990" "1985" "1975" "2001" "2003"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
library(data.table)
library(stringr)
setDT(test)

test[str_detect(year, "^0"), new := paste0("2", year)]
test[str_detect(year, "^9"), new := paste0("1", year)]
```